# Why is this SQL incorrect (MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following query:

```
"DELETE * FROM Participations WHERE scheduleId IN (SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE meetingId = :meetingId) AND userId = :userId"
```

I assign variables using PDO properly.

In response I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM Participations WHERE scheduleId IN (SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE meeting' at line 1}

It is enough that I replace first DELETE with SELECT and query is done properly.
Besides when I test directly in phpMyAdmin the same query with DELETE in it works fine.

I am confused....

Answer (score 1):

Use `DELETE FROM` (note the lack of `*`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly indicates that it is a syntax error near '*'.

Remove * from  your Delete statement

```
DELETE FROM Participations WHERE scheduleId IN 
           (SELECT id FROM Schedule WHERE meetingId = :meetingId) AND userId = :userId
```